# How to show processes list in zabbix in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: process, monitoring, zabbix, htop

I am new in Zabbix, which I am running on about 20 Linux machine (Ubuntu 16.04). I want to see all processes there are on each machine just like PS or hop. Are there any solutions you suggest? I want to have it like the CPU utilization and memory use...

I tried these commands, but I think it is not supported for Ubuntu.

```
proc.mem
proc.cpu.util
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zabbix does not have a built-in item to list all the processes. It would be of a limited use, as you cannot really graph such data, or show a compact history.

You can easily add one yourself, though - just add a new [userparameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/userparameters), using `ps` or `top`. For example, adding the following in the agent daemon configuration file and restarting the agent will give you a new `proc.list` item:

```
UserParameter=proc.list,ps -AH
```

Adjust `ps` or `top` parameters as necessary.

Comment: can you please tell where and how to add it . thank you very much

Comment: Added an example.